# Python current timestamp for UTC with millisecond accuracy

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I want to get the milliseconds passed since epoch for UTC time. This seems like a very simple task for python but I am kinda stuck here.

I could use

```
time.time() * 1000
```

but depending on the underlying system, this could either return the value for UTC or local time.

I could also use an approach like

```
time.mktime(datetime.utcnow().timetuple()) * 1000
```

But I can not get millisecond accuracy with this one, multiplying by 1000 only adds three zeros to the end, but I need exact milliseconds because I need to monitor processes that take less then a second.

Comment: `time.time()` returns the number of seconds since the epoch, which is *defined* as midnight UTC, Jan 1 1970. The only system-dependent factor is whether it ever returns a value with more than one-second precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of getting milliseconds

```
ts =  datetime.utcnow()
print ts.microsecond  #prints microseconds
print time.mktime(ts.timetuple()) + ts.microsecond * 1e-6
```

**output**

```
128852
1409151725.13
```

Comment: This works perfectly, only I wanted the result as an integer, so with a slight edit; 

time.mktime(ts.timetuple()) * 1000 + ts.microsecond * 1e-3 

works better for my case

Answer (score 4):

If you use Python 3.3+, you can use [`datetime.datetime.timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
1409120835.727991
>>> int(_ * 1000)
1409120835727
```